# Capitalizing function isn't working on Visual Studio 2013 (C++)

Tags: c++

i'm trying to make my own function for capitalizing a letter in C++, (stdio.h ONLY!)
The function didn't work as expected on VS 2013, it always gives me weird output *(somthing like alpha's symbol)*,
but it *(the function)* works on 2010,

the function i made for capitalizing a letter, below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

char i;
scanf_s("%c", &i);
fflush(stdin);

printf("%c", i -= 32);

getchar();
return 0;}
```

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**scanf_s**, unlike **scanf**, requires the buffer size to be specified for all input parameters of type c, C, s, S, or [ as mentioned here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

So this line:

```
    scanf_s("%c", &i);
```

should actually be:

```
    scanf_s("%c", &i, 1);
```